# Scale canvas proportionally inside flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <canvas class="colorPicker" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
  <canvas class="colorPicker" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</div>
```

And, this CSS:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div > canvas{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 50%;
}
```

The canvases are not scaled proportionally.  They are taller than they are wide.  This is visible when I paint circles on the canvas.

[image: Badly Scaled Canvases]

(JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/08rckfek/)

Why is this happening?

If I don't use flexbox in the parent div, the canvases are scaled correctly.

Furthermore, it seems weird that I have to specify `width: 50%` at all.  `flex-shrink` is ignored, even if I specify a basis.

How can I make a row of canvases that automatically scale proportionally based on the width of the parent flexbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `align-items` as by default its value is `stretch`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
 document.querySelectorAll('canvas.colorPicker').forEach((canvas) => {
  
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  const radius = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) / 2;

  // Base white circle, so middle has a full color
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius/2, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.fill();

  for (let angle=0; angle<=360; angle+=1) {
    const startAngle = (angle-2)*Math.PI/180;
    const endAngle = angle * Math.PI/180;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
    ctx.closePath();

    const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(centerX, centerY, 0, centerX, centerY, radius);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'hsl(' + angle + ', 100%, 100%)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsl(' + angle + ', 100%, 50%)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'hsl(' + angle + ', 100%, 0%)');
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fill();
  }
});
});
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

div > canvas{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas class="colorPicker" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
  <canvas class="colorPicker" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks.  :-)  Any thoughts on why I have to specify the width, and they don't automatically resize proportionally based on the number of items within the div?

Comment: @Brad it's because you have defined the inline with and by default the min-width will be set to the auto width ... you can try to add min-width:0 then remove width:50% and see what happen ;)

Comment: Unfortunately since these are canvases, the width and height must be defined on the element.  Setting `min-width: 0` and removing `width: 50%` leaves me back with stretched elements.

Comment: @Brad yes sure, you have to define them, I simply explained why you get this result even with flex-grow .. as the default setting is min-width:auto which in your case is 800px and flex item cannot shrink past this size that's why your are obliged to force using width:50% ;) ... but when you added min-width:0 the flex-grow worked as you expected